# Need to pull the oldest active row for each category in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I was wondering if there was an better way to pull the data set I need other then 6 individual select queries.

I have a table called "events" which contains events with a timestamp ( date ), "active" column ( int 1 is active ) as well as a "category" column (there are 6 categories this is an INT ) and a "ispaid" column ( INT 1 is paid ). I need to pull the oldest active paid event by each category. I have it working with 6 different select queries but my fear is with the database getting bigger this might be inefficient down the road.

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this?

```
Events Table
------------
id       INT
ispaid   INT  -- 1 is paid
category INT  -- references another table but dont need to join as of now
active   INT  -- 1 is active
ts       DATE -- event date
```

Comment: Hi Scott, Could you post your 6 Select Queries aswell? I'll see what I can do.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that?

```
SELECT *
FROM events_tbl
WHERE events_tbl.active = 1 AND events_tbl.ispaid = 1
GROUP BY events_tbl.category
ORDER BY events_tbl.ts ASC
```

Comment: The grouping will result in an undetermined `ID` being fetched for a given category. Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20511538/how-to-properly-group-by-in-mysql/20511539#20511539) for more information

Comment: @MostyMostacho read his question he is trying to get the answer for each category

Comment: I know... read the question I linked and you'll see the grouping is wrong... or just answer this question: *What ID are you returning after grouping by category?*

Comment: Hi Guys, thanks for replying. I tried Christophers query and it seems to work. By grouping it I am getting 1 event from each category and by ordering by date asc it seems to be pulling the oldest one. I am going to load in a bunch of test data and do some more testing then write back here but this seems to work. Mostly, I dont have a ton of test data in there yet but what are your concerns with this, it wont pull the correct id?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not getting this wrong, most likely you're looking for something like this:

```
select e1.* from events e1
join (
  select category, min(ts) oldestDate from events
  where ispaid = 1 and active = 1
  group by category
) e2 on e1.category = e2.category and e1.ts = e2.oldestDate
where e1.ispaid = 1 and e1.active = 1
```

This gets for each category the oldest date that has been paid and is active. Then that data is joined back to the events table. The double `where` clause should be faster than just leaving the outer one as less records would be processed in the inner select.